# $.Ajax url address not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I´m using Ajax to load data from my web page. Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>MyAPP</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    </head>

    <span>
    <base href="/aeiserver/public/"><!-- [if lte IE 6]></base><![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


    </span>

    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">



            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                        <h4><strong>MYAPP</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>  


            <div>
                <h3><strong>Data:</strong></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">

                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Select info type:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="list-group">
                                <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onClick="loadData(1)">ITEM1</button>
                                <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onClick="loadData(2)">ITEM2</button>
                                <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onClick="loadData(3)">ITEM3</button>
                                <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onClick="loadData(4)">ITEM4</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadData(option)   {

        getUrl = "myApp/actionurl/" + option;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            datatype: "json",
            url: getUrl,
            contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
            success: processData,
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error getting server data. Please retry.");
            }
        });

    }


    function processData(data, status) {
        if (status != "success")
            alert("Error loading MyApp data. Please retry.");

    }


    $(document).ready(function() {


    } );

    </script>


    <footer>

        <div class="row">
            <br />

            <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
                (C) MyApp - <a href="http:\\www.whatever.com">www.whatever.com</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>




    </body>
</html>
```

My method `"myApp/actionurl"` is never called, but only my current page `"MyApp/index"` (looked at F12 on network section). Seens that `url` is not being interpreted.

I can´t find out what´s going on here, and seend to be a basic error. Help needed...

**EDIT:**

I´ve printed the full code with HTML. The Javascript is included in the middle of the code because I´m using an MVC approach where the footer is inserted by the MVC framework automatically.

Repair that I do use the `<base></base>` tag but as far as I´ve researched it does not affect the AJAX url call.

Comment: It looks like there might be a syntax error can you paste more part of the code?

Comment: is **actionurl** a folder name or a sample name to a complete path of file? if it is a folder, Do you have index file in that folder?

Comment: @Abiodun Other than the `...process data...`, which is just a placeholder, there are no syntax errors.

Comment: can you visit the http://website/folder/myApp/actionurl in your browser?

Comment: Is that ajax inside of a function?  When/how is that method called?

Comment: So when another developer looks at your code and tries to work with the `success` callback, they now have to go hunting down the `processData` function? Why?

Comment: I´ve added the full code at the original post. The actionurl is a controller class that the framework calls, but the problems is going out at the browser, not in the server, because the F12 debug at browser shows it´s calling the wrong url....

Comment: Hi @Mendes, What is your base url? would you mind prepending it on your getUrl variable? so that it goes something like: getUrl = "<?=base_url()?>myApp/actionurl/" + option; as in CI framework (CodeIgniter). Just make sure it's enclosed within the quotation marks. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Vicent that did not work.... URL parameter is not being interpreted at all... Its simply being ignored....